# use whenever gem to setup biweekly cron job

Tags: cron, whenever

Is there anyway to schedule cron jobs using whenever to run every two weeks, meaning first Saturday of the month and the third Saturday of the month.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
require 'activesupport'

every :saturday do
  month_day = Date.today.mday
  if (1..7).include?(month_day) || (15..21).include?(month_day)
    # YOUR TASK
  end
end
```